# How to use the output of gnu diff in C++ code?

Tags: c++, diff, gnu-coreutils

I have the following call to `system` in my C++ code:

```
system("diff --unchanged-line-format=$'%dn\n' --new-line-format='' --old-line-format='' file1 file2 > file.common");
```

My goal is to store line numbers of the common lines between file1 and file2 in a file. However, I need to then read file.common to an array in my C++ code.

The issue is that the content of `file.common` contains the formatting string. For example, instead of

```
1
2
5
```

it is like this:

```
$1\n$2\n$5\n
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you are to parse the output, why don't you use popen?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It solved the issue of having to save and read redundantly. But the result still contains $ and \n.

Comment: `system` is bad legacy artifact. It should *never* be used in modern/new code.

Comment: Since the entire command is in double quotes, you have to escape the backslash character. `--unchanged-line-format=$'%dn\\n'`.

Comment: @RSahu or use raw string format: `R"(unchanged-line-format=$'%dn\n')"`

Comment: @MartinYork, that too. Although the OP has to use that for the entire string. `R"(diff ... file.common)"`